# How check if array is first

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, arraylist

```
var array = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];<br>
var myArray ="first";
```

What i want to do is. If first is first array in the list then do something. Can anyone help me??

Comment: so you want to loop through the `array` until you find a value that matches `myArray`?

Comment: Do you want to check if the first element of the array if a value "first"? You could just use the index for it, for sample: `if (array[0] === "first") { ... } `.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you mean is, how to compare the first item in the array, with the variable `myArray`, and then do something if they are equal.

You can retrieve individual items in arrays with their location in the array (starting at 0). The first item in the array would be retrieved with `array[0]`.

You can then use an if statement to compare your variable, and your fetched item.
For example,

```js
var array = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];

var myArray = 'first';

if (array[0] == myArray) {
  // do something here
}
```